# change background color of notch through Code does not work

Tags: android

I tried changing the color of the status bar it work

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
```

but for the nocth diplay it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
```

Just remove:  `window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);`

Answer (score 0):

**work for me**

---

```
make colors.xml file in -> android -> app -> src ->main ->res->values
paste this code ->
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="cutout_color"> your color </color>
</resources>
```

add in styles.xml -->

```
<resources>
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> <- DayNight to Light 
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> //add
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item> //add
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/cutout_color</item> //add
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/cutout_color</item> //add 
    </style>
</resources>
```